# Multiple sections in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Actually i'm using only **one section**. I sort my data stored in core data by date.

I want to have **two sections** (*latest* and *history*). In my first section "latest" I want to put my latest date and in the other section "*history*" i want to put other dates sorted by date.

My table is editable and I'm using NSFetchedResultsController.

Here is my sample code for **numberOfRowsInSection**:

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Info"
                                    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

    // Define how we want our entities to be sorted
    NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                    initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO] autorelease];
    NSArray* sortDescriptors = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil] autorelease];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSString *lower = [mxData.name lowercaseString];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(name = %@)", lower];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *errorTotal = nil;
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&errorTotal];

    if (errorTotal) {
        NSLog(@"fetch board error. error:%@", errorTotal);
    }

    return [results count];

    [fetchRequest release];
    [results release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your designated "`UITableViewDataSource`" object to return "2" for the ["`numberOfSectionsInTableView:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInTableView%3a) method.

Then you need to return the right thing in your ["`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acellForRowAtIndexPath%3a) method, depending on the section designated in the index path.

If you want an optional section title (e.g. "History" or "Latest"), you can also return an array of section titles via [`sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/sectionIndexTitlesForTableView%3a).

Comment: I modified the two methods: numberOfSectionsInTableView: and tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:. Now i have two sections exactly same. But I don't know how to modify tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:".

Comment: you should save the array(s) you're trying to return (latest & history) as instance variables and then depending on which section is being queried in "`cellForRowAIndexPath`" (where "`indexPath.section`" tells you which section a cell is being requested for), you can return the appropriate item from those arrays.

Comment: But i'm using NSFetchedResultsController and I think that if I use two array it can pose  problems when I edit (deleting) my table

Comment: see the "` NSArray *results...`" bit in your code up there?  Move that code to somewhere where it's only called once (e.g. "`viewWillAppear:`") and then declare NSArray ivars for "`latestResults`" and "`historyResults`" and you won't have to worry about the arrays or tables being deleted out from under you.  :-)  Don't worry, you'll get the hang of this.

Comment: I get Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] when I try to add a new cell.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}
```

This way the tableviewController know's how many sections to create. If you don't implement this method it will create the default number of sections which is 1.

> This method is asked to the  data source to return the number of sections in the table view.
>
> The default value is 1.

The full method description can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW9)

#### Update:

When the tableview is asking you which cell to display for a certain index path you can give the cell with the right data. Presuming you have 2 NSArray's containing the titles for the latest and history rows you could do the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //create cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        //set title for latest
        NSString *title = [[self latestTitles] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell textLabel] setText:title];
    }else{
        //set title for history
        NSString *title = [[self historyTitles] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell textLabel] setText:title];
    }
    
    //Update: add NSLog here to check if the cell is not nil..
    NSLog(@"cell = %@", cell);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How can i set my latest value to my first section and the other values to the second section?

Comment: I get Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] when I try to add a new cell.

Comment: Does your storyboard or nib contains a prototype cell with the identifier "MyCellIdentifier" ?

Comment: I updated the answer, add the NSLog to see if you don't return nil instead of a cell. If your app crashes before the NSLog something else is going on.